# Scaled SVG makes for uneven line widths

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a dynamically rendered SVG that scales based on some CSS (outer container). The problem is that for a lot of sizes, the vertical lines appear of uneven width (I increased the width a bit to better illustrate the problem, but they are supposed to have the same width. I suspect it has something to do with subpixel alignment, but cannot figure out a way to solve this...

Here is the code to an example Line:

```css
.timetable-vertical-line line {
      stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      stroke-width: 5;
  }
```

```html
<svg class="timetable-vertical-line" x="50" y="0" width="100" height="440">
    <line vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="440"></line>
</svg>
```

[image: The Problem]

EDIT: I've also tried using `shape-rendering` which didn't help either

Comment: can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: It's because half of your stroke falls outside the svg canvas. Please try using a viewBox attribute like `viewBox="-10 0 60 440"` for example. Alternatively try `svg{overflow: visible;}`

Comment: @enxaneta thank you for that info! if you make it into an answer I'll gladly accept it